# stomp nodejs not sending header on connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, stomp

I have a super simple nodejs application using stomp to connect to a server using websockets.

Problem is the application is NOT sending the headers I'm telling it to send. Documentation and examples couldn't be clearer about how to send a header, so I have no idea why I'm not seeing mine in wireshark.

```
var Stomp = require('stompjs');
var client = Stomp.overWS('ws://localhost:8080/web/wsendpoint');

var headers = {
      login: 'mylogin',
      passcode: 'mypasscode',
      // additional header
      'Auth-Token': 'token'
    };

client.connect(headers, connectCallback);

var connectCallback = function(frame) {
  alert('connected');
};
```

This connects fine, but the headers seem to be ignored. 
Any one have any idea why this is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good news is, you do are sending your headers to the server. Bad news is, that with DOC-proper code like this:

```
client.connect(headers, connectCallback, errorCallback);
```

I received:

```
11 Mar 11:34:07 - server is connected to 127.0.0.1:8080
11 Mar 11:34:07 - {
    command: 'CONNECT',
    header: {
       login: '[object Object]',
       passcode: 'undefined',
       'accept-version': '1.1,1.0',
       'heart-beat': '10000,10000' },
    body: '' }
```

what clearly suggests, that stompjs is sending `headers` object in login field. Anyway with your piece of code i can see a proper frame:

```
{ command: 'CONNECT',
  header: 
  { login: 'mylogin',
    passcode: 'mypasscode',
    'accept-version': '1.1,1.0',
    'heart-beat': '10000,10000' },
  body: '' }
```

So probably - I guess - having a good code, you are watching at wrong (parts of) packages in your wireshark. Some clues may be in [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/mobile-and-web/9781491944790/ch04.html#ch_adv_stomp_frame).

What I have used for tests is [here](https://github.com/YaroslavGaponov/blackcatmq.git).

Comment: Well I've done a search for the headers in the captured packets with no luck. Searching for url is successful, however searching for 'login', 'passcode' or 'Auth-Token' welds no results.

Comment: Try to search for `CONNECT` in packages content, as this is command client sends to server for negotiation. Headers are few lines afterwards, still in package content, and because you seems to connect properly, this package was send for sure and you have to be able to find it.